# Chrome Address Bar has a delay

Tags: google-chrome, delay

Chrome as a delay (around 1sec - 2sec) between when I first click the addressbar and start typing and showing what I typed. There is only an initial delay, so after the delay the letters, suggestions (and everything) is immediately.

But when I open a new tab or refocus the window the delay is there again.

Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Obligatory question, have you tried disabling extensions?

Comment: @GhostKoi I had this problem right after the installation. Meanwhile I have installed some extensions, but they did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

As typing in the bar search in a lot of different places (bookmarks, history, etc.) try to check if clearing some of your unused history/cache/ etc. can help (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>suppr</kbd>) brings you to the cleaning page.

Another way could be to reduce the amount of elemnts you have in the "bar of bookmarks" (the one you get ON/OFF with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>). Too crowded, it can slow everything.

You may check also if a "bugged" keyword isn't active in the "search engine" part of Chrome. (Parameters > Search engine)

PS: not totally sure of the names as my Chrome isn't in english.